# Phonegap Facebook new plugin for IOS using cordova2.0.0

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am integrating Facebook share feature on IOS using phonegap. I found the link  https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect. In this an updated facebook-ios-SDK is provided. I think the demo given in this site is older one so I am not able to get the Facebook work with new SDK because I am getting many errors in FAcebook SDK files. I need to know how exactly to integrate Facebook with newer SDK.

Thanks in advance..
Ashwini

Answer (score 2):

hi I think this child Browser plugin can be used as FB share ,

Check This Link [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser)
and inside this git we can see one FBConnectExample. check this example.

Comment: Ya that can be used. But it doesn't give native app look for our app.

Answer (score 2):

Work is being done now to update the plugin to work with the latest versions of PhoneGap and the Facebook iOS SDK! It should be done this week.

Check it out on github here https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/pg2.1-ios3.1